# Count elements in ranges of values with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to do a kind-of a BETWEEN operation between 2 SQL queries with LINQ.

I have a collection of Person surnames.

And another collection that contains a collection of beginning and ending value of surnames to search for.

For example, let say I have a range in a table to get the number of Persons with Surnames starting between BA and BE.

```
var person = dc.Persons.Select(p => p.Surname);
var range = from r in dc.Ranges
            select new 
            {
               ID = r.ID,
               StartRange = r.StartValue,  //e.g. BA
               EndRage = r.EndValue        //e.g. BE
            };
```

Now I need the number of persons in every range.

```
var PersonCount = from r in range
                  select new
                  {
                      r.ID,
                      NumberOfPersonsInRange = person.Where(t => t.Surname >= r.StartRange 
                                                              && t.Surname <= r.EndRage).Count() 
                     //This does not work. Gives error that Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'
              }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [`string.CompareTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
person.Count(t => t.Surname.CompareTo(r.StartRange) >= 0)
                  && t.Surname.CompareTo(r.EndRage) <= 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the [`CompareTo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=netframework-4.7.2) (instance) method would be to use the [`Compare()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_StringComparison_) (static) method, which also allows you to specify a Boolean argument to specify a *case-insensitive* comparison if you like.

This method does an alphabetic comparison between the two strings, and returns `-1` if the first string is *less than* the second string, `0` if they are *equal*, and `1` if the first string is *greater than* the second string.

Here's an example of your code which does a case-insensitive comparison to determine if the surname is within the range (note you can also replace the `Where` with `Count`):

```
var personCount = from r in range
    select new
    {
        r.ID,
        NumberOfPersonsInRange = person.Count(p =>
            string.Compare(p.Surname, r.StartRange, true) > -1 &&
            string.Compare(p.Surname, r.EndRange, true) < 1)
    };
```

For more information on comparing strings, check out this article: **[How to compare strings in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings)**.

---

Another approach would be to implement an extension method for the `string` class that contains this functionality, for example:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsInRange(this string value, string start, string end, 
        bool ignoreCase = false)
    {
        return string.Compare(value, start, ignoreCase) > -1 &&
               string.Compare(value, end, ignoreCase) < 1;
    }
}
```

This would help reduce the amount of code you need to write in your Linq statement:

```
var personCount = from r in range
    select new
    {
        r.ID,
        NumberOfPersonsInRange = person.Count(p =>
            p.Surname.IsInRange(r.StartRange, r.EndRange, true))
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. This is also correct. I'm accepting the first answer out of fairness, but this is helpful. Appreciate.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. If by "fairness" you mean that the other answer was better or more helpful, then that's exactly what the purpose of the site is, and is the right thing to do. Cheers!

Comment: This answer is more comprehensive, both are right. Other was just first - less comprehensive, but also correct.